# Выборка всех данных из таблицы БД php MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! делаю выборку данных типа varchar из таблицы таким образом:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM words";
$res = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
  echo "Номер: ".$row['he']."<br>\n";
  $list = $row['he']
}
```

Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы выбирались все данные из таблицы и загонялись в массив через пробел каждое слово?

Чтобы получилось так:

```
$list = "JAVA BEANS
PHP SCRIPTS
SOURCE CODE
JAVASCRIPT GAMES
SSI IS SERVER SIDE INCLUDES
BILL GATES
COOKIES
HTTP AUTHENT;
```

Comment: Зачем вы выбираете из таблицы все поля через `*` если вам нужно в результате манипулировать лишь одним столбцом?

Comment: верно, одним столбцом. Но как сделать так чтобы выбирать все данные из этого столбца и загонять их в массив?

Answer (score 4):

Можно воспользоваться минимум двумя способами.

1) Сделать это в самом запросе:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`he` SEPARATOR " ") FROM `words`
```

В результате сразу получить строку из слов, разделенные пробелом
http://webi.ru/webi_articles/8_14_f.html

2) Выбрать слова по полю `he` таблицы `words`
В результате получим массив слов. Назовем его `$resultQuery`. И далее к результату применить `implode` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php

```
$words = implode(' ', $resultQuery);
```

---

Просто как напоминание про `mysql_` расширение

> **Внимание** Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и
>   будет удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL.
>   Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ для
>   получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной функции:
>   mysqli_connect() PDO::__construct()

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: спасибо за помощь! Вы не могли бы подсказать еще - проверял запрос в php MySQL - все отлично работает! но почему у меня в массив попадает только **первое слово**?
делаю так: `$query = "SELECT wo, GROUP_CONCAT(wo SEPARATOR ' ') FROM words";
$res = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
$list = $row['wo'];
}`

Comment: @Василий Потому что выборка `group_concat` в имени поля получает именно `GROUP_CONCAT(wo SEPARATOR ' ')` а вы еще выбираете поле `wo` зачем-то.... вам нужно групповой конкатенации присвоить имя `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(wo SEPARATOR ' ') as words_list FROM words` и далее у вас уже будет `$row['words_list']` .....а так как запрос даст только одну сразу сконкатенированную строку, то в цикле её не надо уже будет обрабатывать. Достаточно написать `$row = mysql_fetch_array($res); $list = $row['words_list'];` а если версия `php` >=5.4 то вообще `$list = mysql_fetch_array($res)['words_list']`

Comment: спасибо большое @Алексей Шиманский за помощь! Ваши способы и советы мне очень помогли! я приму к сведению про расширение)))